# Drop Down menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am using Phonegap and i am new to both phonegap as well as jquery. I needed to know if i can have a drop down button using jquery. Appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         
            $('.down-list').width($('.dropdown-menu').width()-2);
         
            $('.dropdown-menu').hover(
              function () {
                $('.menu-first', this).addClass('slide-down');
                $('.down-list', this).slideDown(100);
              },
              function () {
                obj = this;
                $('.down-list', this).slideUp(100, function(){ $('.menu-first', obj).removeClass('slide-down'); });
              }
            );
         
        });
```

this code doesn seem to work. It just gives me the text on android emulator. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @dave: The code doesn work in android emulator..

Comment: @Khush You're right, didn't catch that one. I'll delete the comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you solved the problem? If not, you should look into using jquery mobile and why did you want to use jquery to create a drop-down? I am guessing you want to "beautify" the drop-down? Another option is to look at html5 and css3 based drop-downs as those will be hardware accelerated; depending on jquery too much will only make your app run slower because it is being run inside a browser (phonegap)

**Update:**

From personal experience I have realized that you should look into micro frameworks like [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com) or [XUI](http://xuijs.com) or [jqMobi](http://jqmobi.com). I have personally used Zepto and have noticed significant improvements in performance compared with jQM and jQ. All of the frameworks I just mentioned use jQ style syntax so porting to them will not be a problem.

I have blogged about PhoneGap(now Cordova) at http://codejournal.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/what-i-can-use-htmljavascriptcss-for-native-mobile-apps/. I have blogged about other useful stuff for mobile that you can use.